# Rewrite rule pointing root document at a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite requests for `http://www.foo.com/` to return `http://www.foo.com/homepage.php` instead (without redirection). My current .htaccess rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /homepage.php [L]
```

mod_rewrite is installed, and I have `AllowOverride` set to `All` in the site conf. Other rewrite rules work as expected. If I change the rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^$ /homepage.php [L,R=301]
```

...then I almost get the desired behavior; the page is redirected, and the URL ends up with /homepage.php appended. However, I'd like to load the content from `/homepage.php` without redirecting the page.

I've also tried other flags like `P`, `PT`, `R=303`, etc, and none of them came closer than `R=301`.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Edit - a more full .htaccess, as requested:

```
# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Multiviews creates problems with aliased URLs
Options -Multiviews

# Handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
  php_value memory_limit                    256M
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # Site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot
  RewriteBase /

  # link to homepage...
  RewriteRule  ^$  /homepage.php  [L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a rewrite rule. Just use `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Use this line at top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex homepage.php
```

Try this code in your htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # link to homepage...
  RewriteRule ^/?$ homepage.php [L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I realize this is an option, but I'd prefer to accomplish what I'm trying to do via rewrite rules, if possible (I have my reasons).

Comment: I'm keen to know the good reasons. Also please post your full .htaccess in question

Comment: I'm not setting up this site for the first time; I'm transferring it from one location to a new location, and I'm trying to keep as much of the content as similar as possible. Ideally, I wouldn't have to modify the htaccess file at all; the site works at the current location, so if I mimic the settings effectively, everything should work at the new location.

Comment: **Didn't work** doesn't tell any information about the problem.  Q1. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q2. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q3. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q4. Where is above .htaccess located?